# c++ overloaded ==operator wants one AND two arguments

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to overload the == operator in a project I'm doing. the declaration and definitions are:

```
friend bool operator==(const TradeItem& item);

bool TradeItem::operator==(const TradeItem& item)
```

when i compile this it says: 'bool operator==(const TradeItem&)' must take exactly two arguments. So i rework it to have two arguments like this:

```
friend bool operator==(const TradeItem& i1, TradeItem& i2);

bool TradeItem::operator==(const TradeItem& i1, TradeItem& i2)
```

but when i compile this it tells me it takes exactly one argument.... talk about giving me the runaround. anyone know whats going wrong?

Comment: you must create both a function that takes one argument and one that takes 2 ;)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that:

```
friend bool operator==(const TradeItem& item);
```

requires two arguments and:

```
bool TradeItem::operator==(const TradeItem& item)
```

requires one argument.

This is because the non-member version of `operator==` always requires two and the member version requires one. Your friend declaration declares a non-member operator overload.

```
class C {
    friend bool operator==(const C &lhs, const C &rhs);
public:
    bool operator==(const C& rhs);
};

bool operator==(const C &lhs, const C &rhs) { return true; }

bool C::operator==(const C& rhs) { return true; }
```

Also you only need to use the two member version if you need to permit type conversions on the left hand side. E.g.:

```
bool operator==(int lhs, const C &rhs);
bool operator==(double lhs, const C &rhs);

10 == C();
3.0 == C();
```

And you may be able to get away without declaring these overloads as friends of C. Maybe something like:

```
class C {
public:
    bool operator==(const C& rhs);
    bool operator==(int rhs);
    bool operator==(double rhs);
};

bool operator==(int lhs, const C &rhs) { return rhs == lhs; }
bool operator==(double lhs, const C &rhs) { return rhs == lhs; }

bool C::operator==(const C& rhs) { return true; }
bool C::operator==(int rhs) { return *this == convert_int_to_C(rhs); }
bool C::operator==(double rhs) { return *this == convert_double_to_C(rhs); }
```

---

Also since checking for equality shouldn't change the object you should `const` qualify the member functions:

```
class C {
    bool operator== (C const &rhs) const;
}
```

Comment: Just adding a clarification that the person who asked the question might find useful: you probably need only one of those. Except in extreme circumstances, declaring (and implementing) both of those is superfluous. If you are writing this operator as a member function, you don't need the friend declaration and you don't need the two-argument version of it.

Comment: the program guidlines tells me it needs to be friend overload, so im gonna get rid of the member overload. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I also suggest that you look into boost::operator to ease handing of operator overloading. Also if you have the member function version of the operator you most likely do not need to use the friend declaration

Comment: @YaserZhian If you write both, doesn't it cause a compiler error? I guess I could try it to confirm. It just seems like the compiler or linker will be unable to decide which to call if you have an operator which is overloaded as both a member and a friend .

Comment: @Code-Guru Of course it will generate a compile error (it will say that the operator is ambiguous) if you write the two versions correctly and identically (i.e. both using `const &`) and both declarations are visible from the calling site and you actually call the equality operator from somewhere. If these conditions are not met, for example if you don't actually call the operator yet, your class will compile (I think) but you'll have problems later.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `==` is a binary operator. This means it *must always* have two arguments. If you overload `operator==()` as a member function, one of those arguments is the implicit `this` which is passed to every member function.

In your code, you declare a global `operator==()` function that is a `friend` of the `TradeItem` class. At the same time, you are define a `operator==()` as a *member* of `TradeItem`. Pick one; you should not do both.

Answer (score 0):

The class member version of operator `==` takes one argument and the friend version takes two arguments so it should be something like this:

```
friend bool operator==(const TradeItem& i1, TradeItem& i2);

bool TradeItem::operator==(const TradeItem& i )
```

This is because the member version has a hidden `this` argument. The member version will also have precedence over the friend version. You should choose one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The operator== overload that takes in two arguments must not be a member function - declare it as a `bool operator==(const T&, const T&)`.